# Why would authorization logic on OpenCart Admin Panel design like this (weired)?

Tags: php, authentication, authorization, opencart, opencart-3

We have lots of authentication and authorization methods to use (OAuth, 2FA, etc.) to ensure the security of our account on e-commerce platform.
I am recently had a close look on the admin login logic of `OpenCart 3.0.2.0` and try to figure out why the authorization logic design like this:

1. Storage the user_token in session table in DB (Cool)
2. Storage a logged status in PHP memory (Cool)
3. Storage the user_token in admin user's browser (Cool)
4. Give a duration for the token to expire (Cool)
5. *Keep carrying the user_token on the URL GET variable everywhere (???)*

We could check if the user_token from the admin user is valid and has in our session table in DB (which is checked when log in), then we could keep track the logged status in PHP memory, also we can check if this session is expired.

**The question is: Why do we still need keeping user_token on the url get variable everywhere?**

Comment: OC is opensource and free e-commerce platform. So you are free redesign authorization method and even sell it in opencart marketplace. And all will be happy.

Comment: If there are any security issues if we remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user_token variable was added later on after a discussion on the internet about this security flaw.

The idea of a token was to prevent a hacker from sending a user a link with malicious code in the url that would use the Admins authenticated session to hack the opencart admin panel.

With the token in place, OpenCart checks it and logs out the admin in case the token is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What I am wondering why do we need to not only store token in users’ browser and our server, but also carrying on the HTTP GET variable everywhere? Which just seems do not make any sense to me...got confused!

Comment: Because a hacker can exploit a weakness in the code of the admin panel by emailing or sending via skype a link to the Owner of the opencart store (you for example) which sends the password of the admin panel to this hacker or something similar when clicked on. if it didn't have a token, the admin would click on that link and the code would have been triggered. But since the link requires a token, it is less likely that the hacker knows that token. it is just a security precaution.

Comment: Thanks! So how could a hacker send me a link to my admin panel and record my password/token/something like that?

Comment: if he knew a weakness inside opencart, that could be triggered by calling some method say yousite.com/admin/index.php?route=folder/somecontroller/somemethod without the token you as an admin would trigger that method if clicked. I could email you (since your contacts are on the site) a link saying "you have an error on this page, please check ...... " and pass this url, you would click it and trigger the method I expected you to. Of course at this moment I can not provide you with a real hack since I personally do not focus on this. But thats the whole idea behind the token. it would block it.

Comment: Gotcha, much thanks! So I may receive a link say, directly delete some orders or approve some invalid order. I got your point, apperciate.

Comment: Exactly! thats what it blocks.